# devexpress ribbonform object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, devexpress

[ribbon form error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2smGD.jpg)

I have object reference not set to an instance of an object error when click on main form of project and stack trace is at devexpress.xtrabars.ribbon.ribbonform.wndproc(message&msg)

I try open a new form. But i add my controls in form i had this error. i think error source is usercontrol but i cant figure it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: it is not a null reference error i check. error source is usercontrol but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the designer manually?
It seems there are fields within designer which are not initialized. Collapse the InitializeComponent method, and check the field declarations below it. 
In essence whatever fields are declared there, they should be initialized within InitializeComponent() method (It's a convention, not a rule. You can initialize them wherever you want).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the problem. So i delete every user control from project and add winforms. the problem was solved for me. Sorry for steal your time.